# How to compare clock portion of time.Time

Tags: datetime, go, time

I have a time.Time `start` "2019-07-02 01:00:00" and I want to write a function that would tell me if `time.Now()` falls into the range of x minutes before the start time (ignore the date, just the clock portion `01:00:00`)

eg:

case one

```
x = 30 minutes
time.Now() = "2020-11-20 00:45:00" //return True because 00:45:00 is 15 minutes before 01:00:00
time.Now() = "2020-11-20 00:20:00" //return False because 00:20:00 is 40 minutes before 01:00:00
```

case two

```
x = 120 minutes
time.Now() = "2020-11-20 23:00:00" //return True because 23:00:00 is 120 minutes/2 hours before 01:00:00 (like 11pm is 2 hours before 1am of next day)
time.Now() = "2020-11-20 00:00:00" //return True
time.Now() = "2020-11-20 00:20:00" //return True
time.Now() = "2020-11-20 22:30:00" //returns False
```

case three

```
x=1440 // 24 hours
always return true
```

What I have now only solved for case one but not case two. I looked into the time package of go but don't find anything that efficiently solve this. Any ideas?

```
now := time.Now()
trigger : = start.Sub(time.Minute * x))
triggerClock :=  trigger.Sub(trigger.Truncate(24 * time.Hour)) //extract clock portion
nowClock := now.Sub(now.Truncate(24*time.Hour)) //extract clock portion
diff := nowClock.Seconds() - triggerClock.Seconds()
if diff >= 0 && diff < x {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could approach this and selecting the right one would depend upon the meaning of "x minutes before the start time":

- By "just the clock portion" I assume you mean on the current day or, if the current time is after the "clock portion", tomorrow.
- The start/end of daylight savings can result in situations where the obvious answer may be not be correct (but you would need to specify what should happen at these times).
- Do time zones need to be considered? (I will assume no for now but worth thinking about this!).

I would approach this by calculating the minutes between the target and check times as follows:

```golang
func MinutesBefore(target time.Time, check time.Time) int {
    t := time.Date(check.Year(), check.Month(), check.Day(), target.Hour(), target.Minute(), target.Second(), target.Nanosecond(), target.Location())
    if t.Before(check) {
        t = time.Date(check.Year(), check.Month(), check.Day()+1, target.Hour(), target.Minute(), target.Second(), target.Nanosecond(), target.Location())
    }
    return int(t.Sub(check).Minutes())
}
```

Try it in [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8sVCr42feAR) with some test cases.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to truncate the difference, rather than the times, for example:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

const (
    day = time.Hour * 24
)

func within(t1, t2 time.Time, epsilon time.Duration) bool {
    delta := t1.Sub(t2)
    delta = (delta - delta.Truncate(day))

    // Take absolute value of delta.
    if delta < 0 {
        delta = -delta
    }

    // Reduce if the times are closer across midnight.
    if adjusted := day - delta; adjusted < delta {
        delta = adjusted
    }

    return delta <= epsilon
}

func main() {
    start := time.Date(2019, 7, 2, 01, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

    for _, tc := range []struct {
        t    time.Time
        e    time.Duration
        want bool
    }{
        {
            t:    time.Date(2020, 11, 20, 0, 45, 0, 0, time.UTC),
            e:    time.Minute * 30,
            want: true,
        },
        {
            t:    time.Date(2020, 11, 20, 0, 20, 0, 0, time.UTC),
            e:    time.Minute * 30,
            want: false,
        },
        {
            t:    time.Date(2020, 11, 20, 23, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC),
            e:    time.Minute * 120,
            want: true,
        },
        {
            t:    time.Date(2020, 11, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC),
            e:    time.Minute * 120,
            want: true,
        },
        {
            t:    time.Date(2020, 11, 20, 0, 20, 0, 0, time.UTC),
            e:    time.Minute * 120,
            want: true,
        },
        {
            t:    time.Date(2020, 11, 20, 22, 30, 0, 0, time.UTC),
            e:    time.Minute * 120,
            want: false,
        },
        {
            t:    time.Date(2020, 11, 20, 13, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC),
            e:    time.Hour * 24,
            want: true,
        },
    } {
        if within(start, tc.t, tc.e) != tc.want {
            log.Fatalf("test failed for %v, %v, %v", start, tc.t, tc.e)
        }
    }
}
```

You say that you want to return `true` for any `x` of 24 hours or greater, but note that because you want the behavior given in the first example of your case 2, it turns out that `true` will be returned for any `x` of 12 hours or more, because that's the maximum distance between two times if you're accepting the closest distance either within or across a 24 hour period.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the time fraction(clock portion) of a date using the template `15:04:05`

```
var start time.Time
start, _ = time.Parse("15:04:05", "01:00:00")
```

with that we want to subtract `start` by the `now` and check if the result is not bigger than `x`

```
if start.Sub(now).Minutes() <= x.Minutes() {
    return true
}
```

this will work for our first case but when we have a midnight in between it would fail. to fix that we can subtract a day from `now`

```
if start.Before(now) {
    now = now.Add(-time.Hour * 24)
}
```

then here you have it

```
func rangeOf(x time.Duration, start time.Time, now time.Time) bool {
    if start.Before(now) {
        now = now.Add(-time.Hour * 24)
    }
    if start.Sub(now).Minutes() <= x.Minutes() {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

here is the case two test

```
func main() {
    x := 120 * time.Minute
    var now time.Time

    now, _ = time.Parse("15:04:05", "23:00:00")
    fmt.Printf("%t\n", rangeOf(x, start, now))

    now, _ = time.Parse("15:04:05", "00:00:00")
    fmt.Printf("%t\n", rangeOf(x, start, now))

    now, _ = time.Parse("15:04:05", "00:20:00")
    fmt.Printf("%t\n", rangeOf(x, start, now))

    now, _ = time.Parse("15:04:05", "22:30:00")
    fmt.Printf("%t\n", rangeOf(x, start, now))
}
```

all test cases here https://play.golang.com/p/Ijs-rlPCIIJ